# Fetch Data From Multiple Models In One View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, ransack

This seems easy but I can't figure out how to do it

I'm trying to implement Ransack search in my rails app and for that I have a generated a model Cofounder which don't have any fields in it and I have association between Cofounder and CustomUser model which has email and other fields but i only want to search through email using ransack, i have this association between these two:

```
has_many :cofounders
belongs_to :CustomUser
```

(Do i need to have id if Yes how do i do it)

CoFounder Model

```
class Cofounder < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :CustomUser  
end
```

CofoundersController

```
class CofoundersController < ApplicationController

    layout "custom_layout", only: [:index]

    def index
        @q = Cofounder.ransack(params[:q])
        @cofounders = @q.result
        @cofoundes = CustomUser.all
        @countries = Country.all
    end
end
```

and in my index view

```
<% search_form_for @q, url: cofounders_index_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.search_field :email_cont, placeholder: "Search Here" %>
      <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>

<%= select_tag "search_by_country", options_for_select(@countries.collect{|x| [x.name]} , params[:search_by_country] ),{prompt: "Select country"} %><br><br>

<%= select_tag "choose_a_role", options_for_select(@cofoundes.collect{|x| [x.first_name]} , params[:choose_a_role] ),{prompt: "Choose A Role", id: "select", multiple: true} %><br><br>

 <% @cofoundes.each do |cofounder| %>
   <%= cofounder.email %>
 <%end%>
```

it is giving me error code

> undefined method `email_cont' for #

i know email_cont if not a field in cofounder and i'm accessing that field in cofounder which is giving me error, how do i get those values in cofounder for successful Ransack search.

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Not an answer but you need to correct the associations. This `belongs_to :CustomUser` should be `belongs_to :custom_user`.

Comment: I don't know why RanSack is needed for such simple use case. This is something like a sledgehammer to crack a nut. If you want to stick with the overhead you probably have to use a nested attribute name in your search field.

Comment: @ChristianRolle i am on it from last 2 days after a lot of searching i come up with Ransack to implement search in app, and can you plz explain more  "you probably have to use a nested attribute name in your search field" or if possible any link will be good

Comment: Is that "i am on it from last 2 days after a lot of searching i come up with Ransack to implement search in app" your argument for searching via Ransack? If so you probably have to take a step backwards and rethink if you really need a searching gem, or if you probably can do the same result in a one liner yourself.

Comment: well without using gem i guess i have to do a lot of code like i want countries to be searched and categories,  . .
I have no idea how can i do the same result in a one liner.